# Zend Framework 2: Predicate\In with space in MSSQL column name

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, zend-framework2, predicate

I am trying to get following predicate to work using ZF2 and MSSQL 2008.

```
$select = new Select();
$select -> from("MyTable");

$predicateIn = new Predicate\In('Bad Name', array(
"A",
"B",
"C"
));

$select -> where(array($predicateIn));
$resultSet = $this -> selectWith($select);
```

This is the error I get:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Bad'
```

Printing the generated statement displays the following, and can't find a way around it.

```
SELECT "MyTable".* FROM "MyTable" WHERE "Bad" "Name" IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Any additional quotes are escaped and using [Bad Name] results in the same error.
I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following, which worked:

```
$select = new Select();
$select -> from("MyTable")    
$platform = $this->adapter->getPlatform();
$filterList = array("A","B","C")

$predicateIn = $platform->quoteIdentifierChain(array('MyTable','Bad Name'));
$predicateIn .= " in (";
$predicateIn .= $platform->quoteValueList($filterList);
$predicateIn .= ")";

$select -> where(array($predicateIn));
$resultSet = $this -> selectWith($select);
```

I would still like to get the Predicate\In() to work though.